# Draw 4 straight lines on image (overlay)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html4

I need an image to be divided in the users browser by 2 lines horizontally and 2 lines vertically. So that there are 9 pieces the image consists of.

Either doing this by drawing lines or by putting the 9 pieces a little bit apart.

I know of Raphael and paper.js but maybe it can be done (canvas html5 and html4 JS) without additional frameworks.

If you got an approach, would using it also be capable to part a circle by 4 like splitting a cake?

Comment: Yeah, sure you can. (1) set the background image of the canvas to be the image (2) draw the lines you need on the canvas. Peasy-easy. Check for some references on `<canvas>` for it's use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can slice and space an image apart using the canvas `drawImage` function**

[image]

All the work is done by the `context.drawImage` function using some extra parameters

`drawImage` is able to clip a portion of the source image and draw it on the canvas

BTW, `drawImage` is also able to simultaneously scale that  clipped portion.

Here are the arguments to allow `drawImage` to slice the source image:

1. The source image
2. X position on the source image where clipping will start
3. Y position on the source image where clipping will start
4. Width of the source image to clip
5. Height of the the source image to clip
6. X position on the canvas to place the clipped sub-image
7. Y position on the canvas to place the clipped sub-image
8. The scaled width of the clipped image to be drawn on the canvas
9. The scaled height of the clipped image to be drawn on the canvas

And here’s how to use drawImage to slice the source image into 3x3 cells with 10px spacing

```
context.drawImage(

  img,               // the source image
  0,0,               // get the image starting at it's 0,0 position
  img.width,         // grab the entire width of the image
  img.height         // grab the entire height of the image
  x*img.width/3+10,  // make 3 image "columns" with 10px spacing
  x*img.height/3+10, // make 3 image "rows" with 10px spacing
  img.width/3,       // each image column is 1/3 of the original image
  img.height/3       // each image row is 1/3 of the original image

);
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/m89Gg/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image=new Image();
    image.onload=function(){
        slice(image);
    }
    image.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sky-bg2.jpg";

    function slice(img){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var w=img.width;  // original image width
        var h=img.height; // original image height
        var rows=3;       // # of rows 
        var cols=3;       // # of columns
        var cw=w/rows;    // cell width
        var ch=h/cols;    // cell height
        var scale=3;      // also, scale the image down
        var spacing=5;    // spacing between cells

        // set the canvas width to accommodate 
        // sliced/space/scaled image
        canvas.width=w/scale+spacing*2;
        canvas.height=h/scale+spacing*2;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        for(var y=0;y<3;y++){
            for (var x=0;x<3;x++){
                ctx.drawImage(img,x*cw,y*ch,cw,ch,
                    x*(cw/scale+spacing),y*(ch/scale+spacing),cw/scale,ch/scale)
            }
        }
        ctx.stroke()
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is that only for html5 without fallback for the older versions?

Comment: Works in any browser that supports canvas (at this point in time all major browsers support canvas).  The only legacy browser without canvas support is IE<9 and shims are available to make older IE's play.  :)